# buscar en diferentes campos con diferentes inputs mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen día, he tratado de realizar una búsqueda a una base de datos de la siguiente manera.. tengo una base de datos con x columnas (supongamos que para más facilidad, la base de datos tiene solo dos columnas, una columna que se llama día y otra que se llama mes), lo que quiero hacer es que mediante un input buscar solo en la columna dia y mediante otro input diferente buscar solo en la columna mes, que si quiero buscar solo en dia no haya problema alguno, que si quiero buscar solo en mes no haya problema alguno y que si quiero buscar tanto en dia como en mes al mismo tiempo no haya problema. Aquí adjunto el código que tengo y que no funciona :(

Este es la parte del código de la página que realiza las busquedas (donde se encuentran los dos input):

```
<title>busqueda</title>
<p>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="busqueda.php" id="cdr">
<h2>Buscar Usuario</h2>
<input name="dia" type="text" id="busqueda">
<input name="mes" type="text" id="mesqueda">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar"> 
</p>
</form>
```

Esta es la parte del codigo con que se enlaza php y mysql y con el que se realiza la busqueda a la base de datos (estoy 100% seguro que se debe corregir $query que es donde se realiza la busqueda en la base de datos, pero no sé como hacer para que quede como quiero):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$dia="";
$mes="";
$dia=$_POST['dia'];
$mes=$_POST['mes'];
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,"tutorial");
if(($dia And $mes) !=""){
 $query = "SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia LIKE '%$dia%' and mes LIKE 
 '%$mes%'";
 $busqueda=mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
?>
```

Y esta es la parte del código html que crea la tabla donde se van a incrustar los resultados de la busqueda y el php que incrusta dichos resultados de la busqueda en la tabla:

```
<table width="805" border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="75">Día</td>
    <td width="136">Mes</td>
    <td width="225">Año</td>
</tr>

<?php
while($muestra=mysqli_fetch_array($busqueda)){
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Cualquier ayuda será muy agradecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Probe el query y no me marco ningun error, intenta algo asi
<?php
if(!empty($dia) && !empty($mes)){
?>
<table width="805" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td width="75">Día</td>
    <td width="136">Mes</td>
    <td width="225">Año</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $s = "localhost";
    $bd = "nombreBD";
    $u = "root"; //usuario
    $p = ""; //contraseña

    $conexion = new mysqli($s, $u, $p, $bd);
    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
        echo "no conectado";
    }
    $conexion->real_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia LIKE '%$dia%' and mes LIKE '%$mes%'"); 
    $resultado = $conexion->use_result();
    while ($muestra = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $muestra['dia']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $muestra['mes']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
$resultado->close(); 
?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Excelente hermano, funcionó al 100, pero de primerazo al abrir la aplicación me muestra todos los datos que tengo guardados en la base de datos, que línea o líneas del código edito para que al iniciar el código no me salga de primerazo los datos que tengo guardados en la base de datos ?

Comment: @julianvargas  Ya edite la respuesta, agregue el if al principio

Comment: Amigo, ese if nunca se cierra?

Comment: Perdon no se agrego como linea de codigo. Ya quedo al final

Comment: Amigo, si hago lo que me sugeriste se quitan todos los datos que tengo guardados en la base de datos pero me impide hacer búsqueda alguna.

Comment: Te borra los datos? No entendi bien a que te refieres

Answer (score 0):

El concepto es Query Builder o "constructor de consultas". Básicamente vas armando el sql de la consulta según los campos que tenes disponibles.

- Nota1: "disponible" en este caso es que no sea valor cadena vacía o
  no haya sido enviado por post
- Nota2: uso realescape por costumbre
  pero como se espera que tanto día como mes sean números realmente
  sanitizo los datos de entrada usando `intval`
- Nota3: te mantengo el `dia LIKE '%$dia%'`  pero al ser números con un `dia=$dia` ya bastaría

**1** para buscar por dia=A, mes=B o ambos campos coincidentes(dia=A y mes=B)

```
 $dia=isset($_POST['dia'])?trim($_POST['dia']):""; // dia es lo que se recibe o cadena vacía
 $dia=isset($_POST['mes'])?trim($_POST['mes']):""; // mes es lo que se recibe o cadena vacía

 $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
 mysqli_select_db($con,"tutorial");

 $SQL="SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE ";
 if (""==$dia&&""==$mes) : // si no hay dia ni mes definidos mostramos todo 
   $where = "1"; // (cambiar a 0=1 para no mostrar nada)
 else : // dia y mes estan definidos o uno solo de los dos
   $where = "";
   $separador = ""; // la primer condicion no lleva separador

   if (""!=$dia) : // si dia está definido lo agregamos al where
     $dia = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, intval($dia));  // escapeamos el valor convertido a número
     $where .= $separador." dia LIKE '%$dia%'";
     $separador = " AND ";
   endif;

   if (""!=$mes) : // si mes está definido lo agregamos al where
     $mes = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, intval($mes)); // escapeamos el valor convertido a número
     $where .= $separador." mes LIKE '%$mes%'"; 
     //$separador = " AND "; // esta línea no es necesaria con dos columnas pero si para mas ifs si hay mas campos
   endif;

 endif;

 // completamos el SQL
 $query = $SQL.$where.";";
 $busqueda = msqli_query($con, $query);
```

**2** para buscar por dia=A, mes=B o alguno de los campos coincidentes(dia=A ó mes=B)

cambiar donde dice `$separador = " AND ";` por `$separador = " OR ";`